# How to call from viewmodel class function from webview via JavaScriptInterface

Tags: javascript, kotlin, android-webview, android-viewmodel

How to call from viewmodel class function from webview via JavaScriptInterface

```
class JavaScriptInterface {
    private val context : Context

    constructor(context : Context){
        this.context = context
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    fun getWebViewText() : String {
        return "" // text from webview
    }
}
WebView(state = fullContentHtml,
        onCreated = { webView ->
webView.addJavascriptInterface(JavaScriptInterface(context = context), "Function")},
        client = remember { webViewClient },
        chromeClient =remember {chromeViewClient}
    )
```